# Can't run Grails war-file on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-2.0

I'm able to build a war-file in STS, but I'm not able to deploy! Grails version 2.1.1.

I have read all kinds of posts, I have ran clean, update, compile, run-app (runs fine), upgraded Java, changed db-drivers (postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100.jdbc41), removed test from the source path, changed `grails.servlet.version` to 3.0, to name a few.

My setup is pretty vanilla at the moment, so no mystical plugins.

When I try to deploy it using Tomcat or run `grails run-war` I get the following error:

```
Dec 23, 2013 11:39:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 23, 2013 11:39:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 23, 2013 11:39:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class             org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:     Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     locate constructor with Class parameter for class     org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass    at     com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lgrails/test/mixin/domain/DomainClassUnitTestMixin;
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin
... 7 more
```

Comment: Have a look at the following stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410995/groovy-grails-tool-suite-noclassdeffounderror-on-war-deployment. It seems like this is a bug with STS not including the DomainClassUnitTest mixins / the jar file that they're in. Hope that helps.

Comment: I saw that post, tried it all...no dice!

Comment: that is annoying, is it possible to upgrade grails at all and see if maybe that fixes it? I guess it could also be an idea to delete any unit tests that have been created if you wanted to see if it's only the mixin's that are breaking your build.

Comment: Upgraded grails, got into a load of new problems, I'll try and download the latest version on STS and see what I end up with!

Comment: @bschipp that post helped me solve it in the end, but there's too much ad-hoc here for my taste.

Answer (score 1):

For the record.

What I did was copy:

```
grails-plugin-testing-2.1.1.jar
grails-test-2.1.1.jar
grails-test-suite-base-2.1.1.jar
```

(Can be found in GRAILS_HOME/dist)

to Forrest/lib and this to my Config.groovy:

```
grails.war.dependencies = [
    "grails-plugin-testing-2.1.1.jar",
    "grails-test-2.1.1.jar",
    "grails-test-suite-base-2.1.1.jar"
]
```

After that I did clean, compile, and run-war.

I was under the impression that test/prod were kept separated as I don't want my war-file to contain anything related to test.

Answer (score 0):

If u really need to test the `.war` ,but i suppose your `grails run-app` command carried out successfully and application is running. Isn't? If it is!! I suggest you do the following :

I suggest also the above error is a configuration problem to grails and tomcat on **STS** environment it self...seems to me...so ,

```
1. Install `Tomcat 6` Outside for Testing the `.war` after generating using grails console and the command below

2.  Instead of running the war directly from the grails console try to generate a Test ,Development or a production environment `.war` package as follow .
```

N.B You need to have Environment Specific setting for Deployment in your `config.groovy` file under grails `conf` folder..

continued ...

```
grails -Dgrails.env=development war
```

or ,Simply

```
 grails deve war    //here deve is referring to development environment u can do same for test and prod...
```

So.After you have successfully carried out the above steps ...it is time for you to collect you grains into a jar...so find the place of the war generated it is under `targets` folder on your `created grails application folder`.

So ,after that `start` `manually` or `automatically` started `TOmcat6/7`.goto `webapps` server and copy the package you generated above...first Stop `Running Tomcat Server if any!`....Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the followup! Someone will hopefully find this very useful (I did as well!) but I'm not stuck with this problem, I managed to get it working.